# Is there a notion of "fiber object" in a 2-category?

Tags: category-theory

In the 2-category $Cat$ we have the object $Set$ which has the property that its own objects are used to describe fibers. This provides ground for the Grothendieck construction which associates to functors $\varphi : A \to Set$ its category of elements $\int\varphi$, an object of $Cat$, and a functor $\int \varphi \to A$ whose fibers are given by $\varphi$.

When applied to a representable functor, say $A(a,\_)$ this leads to the under-category $a/A$.

This last case can be generalized, using $Cat$ representation, to a general 2-category $K$ with $A \in K$, $a : Z \to A$ by asking for a cat-iso $K(X,a/A) \cong K(X,a)/ K(X,1_A) $ natural in $X$

What are the references / names of concepts that could generalize to a 2-category $K$ what $Set$ is to $Cat$ ?

Comment: near this question are papers of Street : "Fibrations and Yoneda's lemma in a 2-category" leading to "Elementary cosmoi I" (whose results are used in examples of "Limits indexed by category-valued 2-functors")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably interested in the notion of a "opfibration classifier" in a cartesianl closed 2-category endowed with a "duality involution" (an endomap playing the role of $A\mapsto A^\text{op}$ in $\sf Cat$).

Having such a classifying map, i.e. a 1-cell $t : \Omega_\bullet \to \Omega$ with the property that pulling back along $t$ yields a fully faithful functor ${\cal K}(A^o \times B, \Omega) \to \text{Dfib}(A,B)$ is part of the definiton of a "2-topos" in the sense of [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10485-007-9079-2) which also contains the details on what I am talking about.

Comment: thank you for the reference !